# How to implement custom edit and delete button

Tags: c#, jqgrid-asp.net

Is there Anyone who  know that how to  implement custom edit and delete button in jgqrid in asp.net c# and post the data using custom controls via generic handler or web service?

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

Visit  http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html
 in this Row Editing =>custom Edit